# JPA update table structure-what happen to the data

Tags: java, database, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I want to know if I update the JPA entities with data (persist and commit) and then I delete or add attribute(column) from the JPA what will happen to the data? Will the data be deleted from all entities or just the column that I delete?

Additionally, if I delete attribute from the entity class and there is event that updates the table that one column should be deleted?

I was not able to find any documentation that explain this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: What is the query you are trying to execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA implementations offer the possibility to create or update the schema automatically at startup, but this, IMO, should only be used during development, where data can be removed from the database without any problem.

For production, you would use a SQL migration script or even a migration program, or some tool like Liquibase, to update the schema and migrate the existing data to the new schema without losing anything. This is something that you shoul think about, design and test carefully, and which can't be done magically by JPA.